# String formatting in returned JSON objects

Tags: support, c#, json

So I sat down this evening to play with the Stack Exchange API. I downloaded RestSharp, and used it to call the API. One thing the struck me was how strings are formatted, with regards to non-ASCII characters. For instance, the ö in my name was formatted using an XML character entity (I'm guessing it's a Unicode character code). Is this an artifact in RestSharp, or are strings in JSON objects expected to be formatted like this? I'm totally new to these "modern" web technologies such as JSON. Since the days of Perl, PHP4 and ASP, I've been living under a desktop rock... ;)